# The class loader returned by Thread.getContextClassLoader() may fail for processes that host multiple applications

Tags: android, jdom

FIRST STEP THIS CODE IS NO ERROR

```
SAXBuilder   builder = new SAXBuilder  (true);
  Document doc = builder.build ( surveyFile );
```

SECONT STEP  I Call Fragment com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment IS NO ERROR

BUT RETRY FIRST STEP call is Error

```
  SAXBuilder   builder = new SAXBuilder  (true);
  Document doc = builder.build ( surveyFile );
```

> 12-17 09:12:06.397: W/ActivityThread(12130): ClassLoader.loadClass:
>   The class loader returned  by Thread.getContextClassLoader() may fail
>   for processes that host multiple applications. You should explicitly
>   specify a context class loader. For example:
>   Thread.setContextClassLoader(getClass().getClassLoader()); 12-17
>   09:12:06.402: W/System.err(12130): org.jdom.JDOMException: Could not
>   load org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser: SAX2 driver class
>   org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser not found: Didn't find class
>   "org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser" on path: .

Why this Error?

Comment: Which version of JDOM are you using? [JDOM 2.0.x versions are verified to work on Andriod](https://github.com/hunterhacker/jdom/wiki/JDOM2-and-Android), but there is also a known issue with document validation on Android - [the native Android library does not support it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10274555/xmlschema-validation-on-android).

Comment: Found a similar question answered in link below. Hope it helps.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/13455154/4023937